# Is there a narrower monoidal structure definition?

Tags: category-theory

A monoid has a binary operation which is $A\times A\to A$.

This lets us to repeat the same operation for arbitrarily large finite number of elements, like taking sum of a long list of numbers, since our domain and codomain values are of the same type.

So if we think of a list of numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4 and use + operation as binary operator to accumulate the sum:

(left function parameter is used as accumulator, starts from 0 which is identity element for +)

(1) $0 + 1 = 1$

(2) $1 + 2 = 3$

(3) $3 + 3 = 6$

(4) $6 + 4 = 10$

What i realized is; the domain and codomain of the binary operation actually doesn't need to be of the same type to supply this behavior.

As an example if we have a piecewise function, and that function returns

- two times the number if it is odd (as an example 3 becomes 6)
- keep the value if it is even (as an example 4 returns 4)

And we use this piecewise function to form our binary operation

$Even\times Number\to Even$

We are still able to reuse the function over and over again to take sum of a long list.

(1) $0 + 1*2 = 2$

(2) $2 + 2 = 4$

(3) $4 + 3*2 = 10$

(4) $10 + 4 = 14$

So my question is, is there a name for this narrower definition of a monoid-like structure that uses this kind of a binary operation definition ($A\times B\to A$, $A\subseteq B$) instead of ($A\times A\to A$)?

Comment: A few comments on your post: (1) Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) / $\LaTeX$ formatting on this site. (2) You wrote "This lets us to repeat the same operation for *infinite* number of elements". What you mean is "This lets us repeat the same operation for an *arbitrarily large finite* number of elements". There's a difference between an infinitely list and arbitrarily long finite lists. In a monoid, there's no sensible way to "multiply up" an infinite list of elements (what is $1+2+3+4+\dots$ in $\mathbb{N}$?).

Comment: (3) I don't totally understand your example. First, the partial function $f$ you describe is actually a total function: you describe what it does on any input. So $f(x) = 2x$ if $x$ is odd and $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is even. Then I'm not sure what you mean by "use this partial function to form our binary operation". It looks like what you intend is to define $a*b = a + f(b)$. But then it's not clear why the domain of $*$ should be $\text{Even}\times \text{Number}$, rather than $\text{Number}\times \text{Number}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman (1) thanks, i added some latex formatting.
(2) i see, i will update it.
(3) looks like i got lost in translation, i was trying to say piecewise function.
The domain is $Even\times Number$ because the way i accumulate the sum will never supply the function with an odd number as its first parameter. the odd/even situation is just an example, i found different applications of this in programming while trying out things, and realized it actually doesn't fit into monoid's definition but it is capable of doing the same. I wondered if there is a name for it so that i can read more

Comment: You probably already know this, but in functional programming, this way of processing a list by iteratively applying a function to the first element and an accumulator is called [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

Comment: Yes i know, actually i tried to implement filter function using fold on options. Then i realized i was running into this problem of having defined different sets since the function's inputs are not making it exactly a monoid by definition.
Thanks for the heads up though, i haven't read this wiki page before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A binary operation $A\times B\to A$ (without your requirement that $A\subseteq B$) is sometimes called an *action* (of the set $B$ on the set $A$ on the right). Similarly, a binary operation $B\times A\to A$ would be an action of $B$ on $A$ on the left.

If $(B,\cdot,e)$ is itself a monoid, then we might additionally want to require that an action $*\colon B\times A\to A$ respect the monoid operation, in the sense that

- $e*a = a$ for all $a\in A$.
- $b*(b'*a) = (b\cdot b')*a$ for all $b,b'\in B$ and $a\in A$.

If these axioms are satisfied, we call the action a *monoid action* (of the monoid $B$ on the set $A$ on the left). There are obvious dual axioms for monoid actions on the right.

The monoid action axioms are the analogues of the identity and associativity axioms for monoids, and they ensure that given a list $b_1b_2\dots b_k a$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $b_i\in B$ for all $i$, and $a\in A$, there is a unique way to "multiply up" this list.